# Filling a dataframe with multiple dataframe values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some 100 dataframes that need to be filled in another big dataframe. Presenting the question with two dataframes

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([1,1,1,1,1], columns=["A"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([2,2,2,2,2], columns=["A"])
```

Please note that both the dataframes have same column names.

I have a master dataframe that has repetitive index values as follows:-

```
master_df=pd.DataFrame(index=df1.index)
master_df= pd.concat([master_df]*2)
```

Expected Output:-

```
master_df['A']=[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2]
```

I am using for loop to replace every n rows of master_df with df1,df2... df100. 
Please suggest a better way of doing it. 
In fact df1,df2...df100 are output of a function where the input is column A values (1,2). I was wondering if there is something like

```
another_df=master_df['A'].apply(lambda x: function(x))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the index of the dataframe you expect to have? Also, can you post the loop you are using now? It would help to better understand the question.

Comment: Index is 0,1,2,3,4,5 repeated twice. Index is the index of master_df.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to concatenate the dataframes you could just use pandas concat with a list as the code below shows.

First you can add df1 and df2 to a list:

```
df_list = [df1, df2]
```

Then you can concat the dfs:

```
master_df = pd.concat(df_list)
```

I used the default value of 0 for 'axis' in the concat function (which is what I think you are looking for), but if you want to concatenate the different dfs side by side you can just set axis=1.